# 24V Isolated digital input protection TVS

Tags: diodes, opto-isolator, protection, tvs

I am working on creating 24V industrial Grade(Like Siemens PLC I/O) Digital Input circuit,The micro will use the 3.3V supply.
circuit works with TWO input signal one of them is 24V industrial "24V_sig" and should be protected ,the "5V_IN" is from Tac switch. (D1,D2 and D5,D6 In OR Combination).

I have some ideas but I don't know do I think in right way. 
Here is two circuit that i design :
[image: First]

[image: Second]

1-Which way of protecting is better, first or second?

2-in first circuit,is it necessary to add D4 when there is SMBJ28C there ?

3-Should i connect Common to GND ?

Comment: What surge levels (and what specification for surges) are you protecting against?

Comment: why u put tac in isolated part? is it tac as push button in pcb or near the safe side (mcu) ?

Comment: 3- no , that way u break the isolation right?

Comment: The push button is in PCB ,but it is safe and doesn't need protection

Comment: @Hasanalattar yeah it break isolation.So how to ground signal throw D1 path?

Comment: If you need alternative signal input and the signal itself does not need isolation then it should be connected __after__ isolation. Coincidentally that is where you have a ground for it.

Comment: As for the rest of your questions and ideas, you will do yourself a favor if you describe the function of each part to justify its presence in the circuit. I bet you'll have your own answers then.

Comment: @Maple,You mean after optocoupler i should add 5v_sig?Im a little confuse using Bidirectional TVS or unidirectional TVS in isolated part?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant about 5v_sig. My second comment was a suggestion to describe the function of each part, both actual and intended. If you do that your confusion about bidirectional vs unidirectional TVS will be resolved. If you are designing "industrial grade" application you are supposed to know those things, for crying out loud.

Comment: @maple ,i dont know and i ask here :)

Comment: @Andyaka The input should be protected against industrial surge .Digital input is not Fast ,its kind of regular input like this. [link](https://new.siemens.com/global/en/products/automation/systems/industrial/plc/logo/logo-expansion-modules.html#DigitalModules),do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to be numerically clear about what level surge and based on what surge type i.e. what specification are you going to claim it complies with. In the modern world this is what we do - we research a surge requirement and clearly state it.

Comment: @Andyaka,would you please give me some information about surge levels and types? im not familier

Comment: You need to research this yourself. Sorry but it’s a big subject and you need to decide what surge levels you are fighting against. Google en 61000-4-5 from memory

Comment: @Andyaka I study about IEC-61000-4-5 Standard, i want to design this circuit compatible with class 3 ,wich the voltage test level is 2KV and maximum peak current is 1000A ,Wich of above circuit is better ?

Comment: @Danesh_sa so your 5v signal will come to optocoupler? and then where is the return path of it?

Comment: @hasan alattar yeah that right ,i dont know what to do here!common and ground should be seprated.

Comment: put your 5v signal in the safe side !

Comment: The mcu in maybe go trough transistor to drive relay ,and 5V_Sig came from MCU.the important thing is which one should be protected ,The 24V input or the Relay side?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, let’s evaluate the failure modes(or in simple words ways to break your circuit) and then apply protections.
Assuming that your 24V signal comes from a wild industrial environment where everything is possible we could have the following scenarios:
1. Reverse voltage applied on Common and 24v signal,
2. Very high transient voltage applied with positive or negative polarity.
3. High frequency noise riding the 24V or common wire due to machinery operating in the vicinity.

Now to protect against all of these your circuit does need to have a TVS diode, an RC filter and these located such that these devices would not be compromised in any of the failure modes defined above.

Having a TVS diode like SMBJ28C is a good idea but directly putting it on the input would risk damaging this component as early as a higher voltage is applied on 24V line as the current may exceed the max current rating of this component. So it would be better to have this TVS diode after the resistor.

You may decide to add a small bipolar capacitor after the resistors to create a low pass filter and block higher frequency noise from randomly triggering the inputs of your micro controller.

If you shift your TVS after the resistors then you don’t really require D4 because your TVS is doing its job and wouldn’t really allow the voltage on your optocoupler input to go outside the -28v to 28v voltage range.

The answer to your third question, you shouldn’t make ground common unless it’s really required. This is fundamentally why isolation exists and if you connect ground and common then technically your micro controller isn’t protected at all.

Adding to the same point, you can have a button for testing but you should provide it power from an isolated source like a 9V battery or so. You can’t use your circuit’s power without compromising the isolation.

For your resistors just rerun the numbers to evaluate whether you would provide decent current to the optocoupler’s internal Diode so it powers up properly when a valid 24v signal is applied.

Typically the current through a diode can be calculated by the quation below:

Vsource - Vbias = R * I

Where R is total sun of resistances before of after the diode. You must keep Current at the optimal range by playing around with resistor values.

Hope this helps.